# Trouble understanding recursion in Ruby

Tags: ruby, function, recursion, return

I'm following a video about recursion, it's in Ruby

First, the code to append a sequence to an array is easy to understand:

```
def append(ary, n)
  return ary if n < 0
  ary << n
  append(ary, n-1)
end

append([], 5)
=> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

The thing I don't understand is when the reverse_append function is presented:

```
01 def reverse_append(ary, n)
02   return ary if n < 0
03   reverse_append(ary, n-1)
04   ary << n
05   return ary
06 end
```

I understand the function reverse_append does this:

- 02 Checks if n < 0 if so, return the array.
- 03 Calls itself with argument n being subtracted by 1

What I don't understand is why line 04 executes at all if line 02 says that if n is less than 0 then return the array, (which would be empty for what I understand). What's the flow chart for this?

Comment: Work out the program flow with pen/cil and paper. Like 4 runs because `reverse_append` eventually *does* return (over and over).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to recursion: there are many invocations of the same function active. each invocation has its own local variables.
The return only return from the current innvovcation.

The calling function tree will look like this

```
reverse_append([], 2)
..reverse_append([], 1)
....reverse_append([], 0)
......reverse_append([], -1)
......returns []
....[] << 0
....returns [0]
..[0] << 1
..-> [0, 1]
 [0, 1] << 2
 -> [0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Oh, I see, that's the key to recursion! I never thought there were more than one invocation of the same function active; I always thought that the same function call returned to the initial line and continue from there. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your `reverse_append` can be rewritten as:

```
def reverse_append(ary, n)
  return ary if n < 0
  reverse_append(ary, n-1)
  ary << n
end
```

which makes it more obvious that the difference from `append(ary, n)` is the order in which you do `<<` vs. the recursive call.  `append()` says "If I haven't gotten to a negative value, concatenate my `n` to the array, and **then** get the array that results from concatenating all smaller values of `n` and return it", while `reverse_append()` says "If I haven't gotten to a negative value, get the array that results from concatenating all smaller values of `n`, and **then** concatenate my `n` to the result and return it."  If you think about it for a bit, you should see that that determines the order in which the values get appended.